# How to prevent navigating to other page without submit the form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

If the user has fill-up the form half and if the user is navigating the other URL without submitting that form, he should get confirmation and If he confirms then he should navigate. How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

there are two options to resolve this problem - *third party solution*, and a *custom solution*. (I recommend the third party solution, and i'll explain later why)

### third party -  jQuery's jquery.dirty:

##### pros:

- simple syntax
- supported by most browsers
- less likely to cause problems

##### cons:

- an outsourced dependency - generally less safe
- less customizable

[jquery.dirty](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery.dirty%20github&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIL977IL978&ei=E07cYeWhEYe-kwXDkp_IBQ&ved=0ahUKEwil99ayvaf1AhUH36QKHUPJB1kQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=jquery.dirty%20github&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAELADEBM6CQgAELADEB4QEzoECAAQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgUIIRCgAToHCCEQChCgAUoECEEYAUoECEYYAFCMA1igCGCmCWgBcAB4AIABrwGIAcQHkgEDMC43mAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) provides functions for detecting whether a form has been changed or not, and preventing the user from leaving the page while displaying a prompt. It also has other useful functions like resetting the form, and setting the current state of the form as the "clean" state. Example usage:

```
$("#myForm").dirty({preventLeaving: true});
```

### inhouse solution -  using `beforeunload`:

##### pros:

- much more customizable, you can tailor make i.
 - generally safer
 - no dependencies

##### cons:

- not supported by all browsers (most of them don't support a custom massege)
 - you are more likely to encounter problems during coding

The [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.

there are several issues (that are solvable) that we need to face before implementing the code.

#### 1. submitting a form is also an `unload` event

to solve this we will ad a flag to tell us that the form was submitted.

```
var formSubmitting = false;
var setFormSubmitting = function() { formSubmitting = true; };

window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (formSubmitting) {
            return undefined;
        }

        var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';
        
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; 
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
};
```

#### 2. What happens when the user doesn't change anything?

to solve this we would ad a `dirty` using an `isDirty` method to trigger the prompt on relevant occurrences.

var isDirty = function() { return false; }

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (formSubmitting || !isDirty()) {
            return undefined;
        }
        
        var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    });
};
```